# Error en NetBeans con conexión a SQL SERVER: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

Buen día,

Al tratar de ejecutar un código que llama a la conexión con la BD me arroja error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException.
El error se presenta al ejecutar el metodo activado por le botón

Comparto el códido donde se configura el error y el códido de la conexión de con la BD, además del error completo

```js
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import tveterinaria.conexion;


/**
 *
 * @author wolfc
 */
public class citas extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form citas
     */
    public ResultSet res;
    public citas() {
      initComponents();

      this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      Image imagen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("icon/incono.png"));
      this.setIconImage(imagen);
      cargarcomboboxdueno(jcdueno);
      cargarprofe(jcprofesional);
      //cargarmascota(jcmascota);


    }

    public void consultar() {
      DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) jtcitas.getModel();
      modelo.setRowCount(0);
      res = tveterinaria.conexion.Consulta("Select * from citas");

      try {
        while (res.next()) {
          Vector v = new Vector();
          v.add(res.getInt(1));
          v.add(res.getDate(2));
          v.add(res.getString(3));
          v.add(res.getInt(4));
          v.add(res.getInt(5));
          v.add(res.getInt(6));
          v.add(res.getString(7));
          modelo.addRow(v);
          jtcitas.setModel(modelo);

        }

      } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
      }
    }

    public void consultacitaiddueno() {
      DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) jtcitas.getModel();
      modelo.setRowCount(0);
      res = tveterinaria.conexion.Consulta("Select * from citas where iddueno =" + jcdueno.getSelectedItem() + "");
      try {
        while (res.next()) {
          Vector v = new Vector();
          v.add(res.getInt(1));
          v.add(res.getDate(2));
          v.add(res.getString(3));
          v.add(res.getInt(4));
          v.add(res.getInt(5));
          v.add(res.getInt(6));
          v.add(res.getString(7));
          modelo.addRow(v);
          jtcitas.setModel(modelo);

        }

      } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
      }
    }

    public void consultacitaidmascota() {
      DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) jtcitas.getModel();
      modelo.setRowCount(0);
      res = tveterinaria.conexion.Consulta("Select * from citas where idmascota =" + jcmascota.getSelectedItem() + "");
      try {
        while (res.next()) {
          Vector v = new Vector();
          v.add(res.getInt(1));
          v.add(res.getDate(2));
          v.add(res.getString(3));
          v.add(res.getInt(4));
          v.add(res.getInt(5));
          v.add(res.getInt(6));
          v.add(res.getString(7));
          modelo.addRow(v);
          jtcitas.setModel(modelo);

          txtidcita.setText(res.getString(1));
          txtidcita.setText(res.getString(2));
          txtidcita.setText(res.getString(3));
          txtidcita.setText(res.getString(4));
          txtidcita.setText(res.getString(5));
          txtidcita.setText(res.getString(6));
          txtidcita.setText(res.getString(7));

        }

      } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
      }
    }
    DefaultComboBoxModel com;
    public void consultacitaidprofe() {
      DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) jtcitas.getModel();
      modelo.setRowCount(0);
      res = tveterinaria.conexion.Consulta("Select * from citas where idprofesional =" + jcprofesional.getSelectedItem() + "");
      try {
        while (res.next()) {
          Vector v = new Vector();
          v.add(res.getInt(1));
          v.add(res.getDate(2));
          v.add(res.getString(3));
          v.add(res.getInt(4));
          v.add(res.getInt(5));
          v.add(res.getInt(6));
          v.add(res.getString(7));
          modelo.addRow(v);
          jtcitas.setModel(modelo);

        }

      } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
      }
    }


    public void cargarcomboboxdueno(JComboBox jcdueno) {
      conexion con = new conexion();
      String sql = " SELECT iddueno from citas group by iddueno ";
      try {
        Connection cn = con.getConexion();
        PreparedStatement entrada = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = entrada.executeQuery();
        jcdueno.addItem("Seleccione la cédula del dueño");
        while (rs.next()) {
          jcdueno.addItem(rs.getInt(1));
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + e);
      }
    }
    public void cargarprofe(JComboBox jcprofesional) {
      {
        conexion con = new conexion();
        String sql = " SELECT idprofesional from citas group by idprofesional ";

        try {
          Connection cn = con.getConexion();
          PreparedStatement entrada = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
          ResultSet rs = entrada.executeQuery();
          jcprofesional.addItem("Seleccione la cédula del profesional");

          while (rs.next()) {
            jcprofesional.addItem(rs.getInt(1));
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + e);
        }
      }
    }
    public void cargarmascota(JComboBox jcmascota) {

      conexion con = new conexion();

      if (jcdueno.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Seleccione la cédula del dueño")) {
        String sql = " SELECT idmascota from citas group by idmascota";
        try {
          Connection cn = con.getConexion();
          PreparedStatement entrada = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
          ResultSet rs = entrada.executeQuery();
          jcmascota.addItem("Seleccione el ID de la mascota");

          while (rs.next()) {
            jcmascota.addItem(rs.getInt(1));
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + e);
        }

      } else {
        com = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        jcmascota.setModel(com);
        String sql = " SELECT idmascota from citas where iddueno=" +
          jcdueno.getSelectedItem() + "group by idmascota";
        try {
          Connection cn = con.getConexion();
          PreparedStatement entrada = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
          ResultSet rs = entrada.executeQuery();
          jcmascota.addItem("Seleccione el ID de la mascota");

          while (rs.next()) {
            jcmascota.addItem(rs.getInt(1));
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + e);
        }
      }
    }


    private void btnconsultarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      // TODO add your handling code here
      if (jcprofesional.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Seleccione la cédula del profesional") &&
        jcdueno.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Seleccione la cédula del dueño")) {
        consultacitaidmascota();
      } else {
        if (jcmascota.getSelectedItem().equals("Seleccione el ID de la mascota") &&
          jcdueno.getSelectedItem().equals("Seleccione la cédula del dueño")) {
          consultacitaidprofe();
        } else {
          if (jcmascota.getSelectedItem().equals("Seleccione el ID de la mascota") &&
            jcprofesional.getSelectedItem().equals("Seleccione la cédula del profesional")) {
            consultacitaiddueno();
          } else {
            if (jcmascota.getSelectedItem().equals("Seleccione el ID de la mascota") &&
              jcdueno.getSelectedItem().equals("Seleccione la cédula del dueño") &&
              jcprofesional.getSelectedItem().equals("Seleccione la cédula del profesional")) {
              consultar();
            } else {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Coma mierda");
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Adicionalmente comparto el metodo de la conexión a la BD el cual arroja el error

```js
public static ResultSet Consulta(String consulta) {
  Connection con = getConexion();
  Statement declarar;
  try {
    declarar = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet respuesta = declarar.executeQuery(consulta);
    return respuesta;
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en consultas" + e.getMessage(),
      "Error de Conexion consulta", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Si bien es cierto que el metodo devuelve un valor null, es código reciclado tal al pie de la letra y nunca antes había arrojado un error similar. Incluso en otras partes del proyecto se usa de la misma manera el metodo y no se ve afectado por el error.

Comment: Intenta poniendo esta línea: `res = tveterinaria.conexion.Consulta("Select * from citas");` dentro de tu bloque `try { ... }`. Así estarías capturando la posible excepción. Saludos

Comment: revisa si es declarar la variable null, agrega un poco más de información acerca del error

Comment: Lo puse en el try, pero continua sacando la excepción de la conexión. Tambien declaré la variable null y tampoco